# MySQL load_file() for .zip folders

Tags: mysql, windows-10

I have a couple files that I want to store together in a blob type column of a mysql table. So I just put them into a folder and then zipped it. I've never had any trouble storing images, text and pdf files using the load_file() function, but when I try with the .zip folder I get back a NULL value.
What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: Yeah ok, but the question then becomes how to store multiple files into a single column of type blob of a mysql table. Any idea other than zipping the files together?

Comment: Show us the code being used to do the `INSERT` and tell us what application is doing the work (PHP?  Java?  VB?  other?)

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Due to the size I post a comment as an answer. Add your issue log to the question by the same way. Also show values for `secure_file_privilege` and `max_allowed_packet` variables, the size of the file to be loaded, and ensure that your account have FILE privilege.

Comment: how big is the zip file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have noted the same phenomenon.

It does seem a bit strange indeed and OS related. Here is the result of my investigation (using MARIA DB 10.4, Windows 10 Pro20H2):

In a given folder, `C:\zipfolder` for ex., I've created a textfile `zipdoc.txt` with some text content and a zip file containing the textfile.

This gives the folowing `load_file` output:

```
select load_file('C:\\zipfolder\\zipdoc.txt');
+----------------------------------------+
| load_file('C:\\zipfolder\\zipdoc.txt') |
+----------------------------------------+
| zipcontent text                        |
+----------------------------------------+

select load_file('C:\\zipfolder\\zipdoc.zip');
+----------------------------------------+
| load_file('C:\\zipfolder\\zipdoc.zip') |
+----------------------------------------+
| NULL                                   |
+----------------------------------------+
```

Changing the file extension from `.zip` to `.zip_` for ex. fixes the issue:

```
select load_file('C:\\zipfolder\\zipdoc.zip_');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| load_file('C:\\zipfolder\\zipdoc.zip_')                                                                                               |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| PK♥♦¶     FÄLR├SAÏ☼   ☼
   zipdoc.txtzipcontent textPK☺☻¶ ¶     FÄLR├SAÏ☼   ☼
       ☺         zipdoc.txtPK♣♠    ☺ ☺ 8   7      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, it looks like Windows 10 is blocking the access to .zip files in a more restrictive way than other files.

Giving `EVERYONE` access to the zip-file allows the `load_file` function accessing of the original zip-file. After granting the access with the following Powerhell script (adopted from [here](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/04/18/how-to-manage-file-system-acls-with-powershell-scripts/)):

```
$acl = Get-Acl C:\zipfolder\zipdoc.zip
$AccessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("Jeder","Read","Allow")
$acl.SetAccessRule($AccessRule)
$acl | Set-Acl C:\zipfolder\zipdoc.zip
```

load_file is able to access the zipfile:

```
select load_file('C:\\zipfolder\\zipdoc.zip');
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| load_file('C:\\zipfolder\\zipdoc.zip')                                                                                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| PK♥♦¶     FÄLR├SAÏ☼   ☼
   zipdoc.txtzipcontent textPK☺☻¶ ¶     FÄLR├SAÏ☼   ☼
       ☺         zipdoc.txtPK♣♠    ☺ ☺ 8   7      |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

So, the solution is to grant `EVERYONE` access to the zip-files or just changing the extension of the files (It remains a task for admins to find a more restrictive working access level).

Complement: As mentioned by @Álvaro González, the use of an archiving program that sets the appropriate rights is also a solution.

Comment: Great research! The key point seems to be what tool you use to create the ZIP archive. 7-Zip sets access for the user that creates the archive but Windows Zip Folders sets it to `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

Comment: @IDK The problem seems to be solved, but from my own experience I would advise against storing large amounts of file content in the database as the performance, especially of MySQL InnoDB tables, decreases significantly as the table size increases. Instead, I recommend storing the files in a file system and only storing the relative path in the database, possibly with some metadata such as size and file time.

Comment: This is strange... your `@@secure_file_privilege` is set to empty string and allows file operations with any folder, and at the same time the account which is used for MySQL service execution may have restricted privileges in the filesystem? This looks like incorrect/illogical MySQL and OS settings.

Comment: @Akina There is nothing special in my MySQL / OS configuration. The problematic part is the behavior of the Explorers zip functionality which sets too restrictive access level for the archives created. Files created by (all) other archivers / applications are accessible to the MySQL service, regardless of the `secure_file_privilege` setting.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot reproduce the problem. See console output:

```sql
mysql> CREATE TABLE test (val BLOB);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.29 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO test SELECT LOAD_FILE('C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\test.sql');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.05 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> INSERT INTO test SELECT LOAD_FILE('C:\\ProgramData\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 8.0\\Uploads\\test.zip');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.04 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT LENGTH(val) FROM test;
+-------------+
| LENGTH(val) |
+-------------+
|        5603 |
|       17725 |
+-------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```